# IEEE754 Numbers

Tags: javascript, numbers, ieee-754, ieee

In which cases is `n + 0` not equal to `n` where n is a number (in the IEEE754 standard, or more precise a double-precision floating-point number/64 Bit float)?

So where:

```
function isNotSame(n: number) {
  return n + 0 !== n;
}
```

Does return true.
For example:

```js
function isNotSame(n) {
  return n + 0 !== n;
}

console.log(isNotSame(Number.NaN));
```

Returns true;

Comment: NaN should be the only case.

Answer (score 1):

`-0` if you use `Object.is` to compare:

```js
Object.is(-0 + 0, -0)
//=> false
```

`NaN` if:

```js
NaN + 0 === NaN
//=> false
```

But:

```js
Object.is(NaN + 0, NaN)
//=> true
```